# Bluetooth auto-connect not going through

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth

I finally got Bluetooth working on my late 2011 8,3 MacBook Pro running 11.10-amd64 Ubuntu.

However, I'm having some weird problems that I've noticed were pretty global across what I was doing.

Essentially, my Bluetooth device will be able to connect, but it won't actually get used or utilized for anything unless I intervene to make stuff happen. My device will connect initially to my computer, then drop the connection and go into pairing mode, as if it can't see anything it's automatically connected to. I'll see the device connect and then disconnect every so often on my computer, apparently as it looks for the computer.

It seems like some kind of handshake is failing. If I wait until my device connects to the computer for the short period that it does and quickly use `blueman` to "Setup..." the device (ie: connect it as a "Headset Service" and "Audio Sync," then it works. It connects just fine and I can use it. However, the connection isn't automatic and persistent unless I intervene and force it into connecting as a A2DP headset.

Is there something I could do to try and determine what's going wrong here? I'd simply like the computer to automatically connect to the device as soon as it's detected, so that when I start my operating system, things "just work™."